# How to implement methods add(value, index) and remove(index) for the SinglyLinkedList

Tags: javascript

I need to implement methods for removing and adding items by index. I was able to implement only at the beginning and end of the list. I understand that I have to break an array by index, add a new element to the end of the first list. and then add another part to it? Please help

```
   class Node{
        constructor(value, next, prev){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
    class SinglyLinkedList{
        constructor(){
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
        }

        addFirst(value){
            let node = new Node(value, this.head, null);
            if (this.head){
                this.head.prev = node;
            }
            else {
                this.tail = node;
            }
            this.head = node;
        }
        removeFirst(){
            if (!this.head){
                return null;
            }

            let value = this.head.value;
            this.head = this.head.next;

            if (this.head) {
                this.head.prev = null;
            }
            else {
                this.tail = null;
            }

            return value;
        }
        toString(){
            let str = "";
            let current = this.head;
            while (current){
                str += current.value + " ";
                current = current.next;
            }
            console.log(str.trim());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you defining the `this.prev` if its a singly linked list?

Comment: I could not implement this method without "prev"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add(value, index)` will look like this -

```
   add(value, index){
       let node = new Node(value, null, null);
       if(!this.head){
          this.head = node;
       } else if(index == 0) {
          node.next = this.head;
          this.head = node;
       } else {
          let current = this.head;
          let d = 1;
          while(current !== NULL){
            if(d === index){
              node.next = current.next;
              current.next = node;
              break;
            }
            current = current.next;
            d++;
          }
       }
        return head;
     }
```

Notice here the algorithm:

1. Create a new node with given `value`.
2. if the `this.head` is currently `NULL` then set the new node to `this.head`
3. if the given `index` is 0 then also set the node to `this.head`
4. else loop over the linked list and find the right position and set the node there

The `remove(index)` method will look like this:

```
remove(index) {
   if(!this.head){
     return;
   }

   let temp = this.head;
   if(index === 0){
     this.head = temp.next;
     return;
   } 

   for(let i=0;temp!==null && i<index - 1;i++){
      temp = temp.next;
      if(temp === null || temp->next === null){
        return;
      }

      let next = temp.next.next;
      temp.next = next;
   }
 }
```

Notice here the algorithm for `remove(index)` is also very similar:

1. if the `this.head` is not defined yet then return
2. if the node to be removed is the head then assign new head and return
3. else loop over the linked list until the position is found then change the next properties to remove the node at the desired position

Answer (score 0):

You can implement removeAtIndex() in the following way :

```
 removeAtIndex(index){
        if (!this.head){
            return null;
        }

       var i = 1; 
       var temp = this.head;
       var save;
       console.log(temp);
       while(i < index && temp){
             save = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
            i++;
       }
        if(temp){
            save.next = temp.next;           
        } else{
            save.next = undefined;
        }

        return temp.value;
  }
```

Basically just iterate to that index and maintain reference to the node before it and the reference to the node after the index of node which you want to delete. And simply save the reference of next node node which you want to delete in the next of the previous node of the node which you want to delete.

You an implement add in the similar way.

In the snippet `removeAtIndex()` functionality is demonstrated you can make addAtIndex in the same way.

```js
class Node{
        constructor(value, next, prev){
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
    class SinglyLinkedList{
        constructor(){
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
        }

        addFirst(value){
            let node = new Node(value, this.head, null);
            if (this.head){
                this.head.prev = node;
            }
            else {
                this.tail = node;
            }
            this.head = node;
        }
        removeFirst(){
            if (!this.head){
                return null;
            }

            let value = this.head.value;
            this.head = this.head.next;

            if (this.head) {
                this.head.prev = null;
            }
            else {
                this.tail = null;
            }

            return value;
        }
        removeAtIndex(index){
            if (!this.head){
                return null;
            }

           var i = 1; 
           var temp = this.head;
           var save;
           
           while(i < index && temp){
                 save = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
                i++;
           }
            if(temp){
                save.next = temp.next;           
            } else{
            
              save.next = undefined;
            }

            return temp.value;
        }
        toString(){
            let str = "";
            let current = this.head;
            while (current){
                str += current.value + " ";
                current = current.next;
            }
            console.log(str.trim());
        }
    }
    list  = new SinglyLinkedList();
    list.addFirst(1);
    list.addFirst(2);
    list.addFirst(3);
    list.removeAtIndex(2);
    console.log(list.toString());
```